# Can't make custom segue in Xcode 10/iOS 12

Tags: ios, custom-transition

I'm having the hardest time implementing a presentation of a drawer sliding partway up on the screen on iPhone.

EDIT: I've discovered that iOS is not respecting the .custom modalTransitionStyle I've set in the Segue. If I set that explicitly in `prepareForSegue:`, then it calls my delegate to get the `UIPresentationController`.

I have a custom Segue that is also a UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate. In the `perform()` method, I set the destination transitioningDelegate to self:

```
self.destination.transitioningDelegate = self
```

and I either call `super.perform()` (if it’s a Present Modal or Present as Popover Segue), or `self.source.present(self.destination, animated: true)` (if it’s a Custom Segue, because calling `super.perform()` throws an exception).

The `perform()` and `animationController(…)` methods get called, but never `presentationController(forPresented…)`.

Initially I tried making the Segue in the Storyboard "Present Modally" with my custom Segue class specified, but that kept removing the presenting view controller. I tried "Present as Popover," and I swear it worked once, in that it didn't remove the presenting view controller, but then on subsequent attempts it still did.

So I made it "Custom," and `perform()` is still being called with a `_UIFullscreenPresentationController` pre-set on the destination view controller, and my `presentationController(forPresented…)` method is never called.

Other solutions dealing with this issue always hinge on some mis-written signature for the method. This is mine, verbatim:

```
public func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController?
```

I've spent the last four days trying to figure out “proper” custom transitions, and it doesn't help that things don’t seem to behave as advertised. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Rick, I have a hard time figuring out, how your custom transition is going wrong. Can you maybe post the code for your custom transition or attach the link to a minimal test example?
Also I assume you are using two standard ViewControllers, no NavigationController involved. Am I correct?

Comment: The presenting view controller is inside a UINavigationController (it’s the only one). I can’t post the code at the moment but will later today.

Comment: After reading your question again, I assume, that you want to have a drawer that overlays your current view, similar to the one in Apple Maps.
As far as I know, you should not do this using to view controllers, as on iOS only one ViewController can be shown at the same time, but use a UIView instead.

Comment: I don’t think that’s true. You can have split view controllers on iPhone, and I’ve seen an example in a WWDC video where they make a popover on iPhone.

Comment: Hm, I would have to recheck, but if using a UIView instead of a separate ViewController also would be fine for you, here is an excellent tutorial, that shows how to implement drawers on iOS: https://www.raywenderlich.com/299-how-to-create-your-own-slide-out-navigation-panel-in-swift

Comment: I really want to use a custom UIViewController; there's some logic in this that I don't want polluting my main view controller. I'm noticing that iOS is not respecting my segue’s specified presentation style (It should be Custom, but in -prepareForSegue: it's UIModalPresentationFullScreen).

Comment: I've edited the question to show that it seems to be a bug in iOS. Figures.

Comment: I have created an answer, that should achieve the same effect (2 UIViewControllers on one screen, which can be animated like a drawer), but without a custom segue. Maybe this would be a good solution for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a custom presentation segue, you could use a `Container View` for your drawer. This way, you can use a UIViewController for your Drawer content, while avoiding the issue with the custom segue.

You achieve this in two steps:
First pull a Container View into your main view controller and layout it properly. The storyboard would look like this: (You can see you have two view controllers. One for the main view and one for the drawer)

[image]

Second, you create an action that animates the drawer in and out as needed. One simple example could look like this:

```
@IBAction func toggleDrawer(_ sender: Any) {
    let newHeight: CGFloat
    if drawerHeightConstraint.constant > 0 {
        newHeight = 0
    } else {
        newHeight = 200
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.drawerHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Here, I simply change the height constraint of the drawer, to slide it in and out. Of course you could do something more fancy :)

You can find a demo project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/789ydphg4j6qoq0/DrawerDemo.zip?dl=0).